# How to build OpenCV with Debug flags

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, cmake-gui

I am currently trying to debug a chessboard corner detection algorithm in OpenCV. To do so, I have uncommented the

```
#define DEBUG_CHESSBOARD
```

line in the source code below.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp

I am then trying to build using the CMake GUI on Windows. When I do this, I keep running into the error "Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/highgui.hpp", evidently due to line 89 in the source code linked above (also shown below).

```
#ifdef DEBUG_CHESSBOARD
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
```

I have looked everywhere and not sure how to resolve the issue. There is a related comment in the file that says that says

```
// Requires CMake flag: DEBUG_opencv_calib3d=ON
#define DEBUG_CHESSBOARD
```

but I cannot figure out how to turn this flag on.

If anyone has any thoughts on this, I would really appreciate it! Thank you so much!

Comment: ***I keep running into the error "Cannot open include file*** Did you set your compilers include path?

Comment: I see that module is here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/modules/highgui/include/opencv2

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by modifying CMakeLists.txt at opencv-master/modules/calib3d/CMakeLists.txt.

You have to move the "list(APPEND debug_modules opencv_highgui)" line out of the if statement. I'm sure there's a way to set the DEBUG_opencv_calib3d directly but I haven't figured that out, but this hacky solution works.